# How does npm start work? What all processes are happening in the background?

Tags: reactjs, development-environment

Can anyone explain what actually happens behind the scene in a React App when we run npm start? How is a react app loaded?

Comment: Are you specifically asking about Create React App? If so, at least [this blog post](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/what-does-create-react-app-actually-do-73c899443d61) explains it a bit more.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

An npm script is just a shortcut to run a series of node commands on your project.
Any npm script, meaning any node.js commands listed under a package.json file's "scripts" section, are executed through node.js when you call them.  So `npm start` runs the node script that is listed under `start` in the package.json.  As in the article that cbr mentioned in a comment, in the case of `create-react-app`, this happens:

> A new instance of the WebpackDevServer from the library of the same name is created, passing in the compiler and configuration. Webpack is run here by the WebpackDevServer. A listener method on the instance is called, passing in the port and host values. This then clears the console and puts up the text “ Starting the development server…”. The browser is opened with the correct dev URL. Lastly, two listeners are added for when the process is killed, which turns off the web server, and exits the start.js process.

That's a great article @cbr linked and highly recommended.  But that is just for CRA.  If you are [setting up a react project from scratch](https://medium.com/fbdevclagos/creating-react-apps-from-scratch-set-up-webpack4-for-a-react-project-ca0bb0517316) (highly recommended if you are just starting to learn all this stuff), your `start` script might look like this:

```js
"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
```

This tells webpack to spin up a development server, serve the files live, and open the browser to the port you specify in the `webpack.config` file (or it will use the [default 8080](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverport)).  If you already ready to build your project for final deployent, you would write a `build` script and run `npm run build`.  It might look like this:

```js
"build": "webpack --mode production"
```

Learning about webpack will help you understand what's happening under the hood with most react projects.  Hope that helps, and thanks @cbr.

Comment: Very informative! Summarizing start would be like "test locally the app" right?

Comment: That's *typically* what people have in their `start` scripts for react frontend projects, but it doesn't have to be.  A script could be constructed to do anything you want, i.e. start up a nodejs server, build an npm package, run a series of file manipulation commands, etc.  The fact that its called `start` is just a naming convention most of us use for running the app locally for development.